# GUI project in QT Creator not working after tinkering it togheter

Tags: python, c++, qt

Have put some script together from snippets of other script.  I'm trying to create a GUI for a python script (HHDB.py) that decrypts a backup. This script needs parameters like password, location of folder with encrypted files and destination to write encrypted files.

Used QT Creator to make a nice gui with a button to browse to folder with encrypted files. The path of this is showed in a textedit field.
Same for the destination.
Then there is a field to enter the known password.
At last there is a button to run the HHBD script with the parameters password, origin and destination location.

As I have no idea on where everything goes wrong and the debugger gives no errors (anymore), i need a coders eye to point me to my (many) flaws.

Thanks already to take a look at the code beneath:

Googled a lot but many found solutions were giving errors to debug, look up and replace :-(

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDir>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QProcess>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QString backup_dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,tr("Choose HiSuite Backup Folder"), QDir::homePath(), QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(backup_dir.replace('/','\\'));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

    QString destination_dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,tr("Choose Destination Folder"), QDir::homePath(), QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    ui->textEdit_2->setPlainText(destination_dir.replace('/','\\'));

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString passwordstring = ui->password->toPlainText();

    QProcess process;
    QString scriptFile =  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "./HHBD.py";

    QString pythonCommand = "python " + scriptFile +
                        " passwordstring" +
                        " backup_dir.replace('/','\\')" +
                        " destination_dir.replace('/','\\')";

    printf("PyCommand: %s\n", pythonCommand.toStdString().c_str());
    process.start (pythonCommand);

}
```

I would like to push "pushButton_3" the script executes the HHBD.py script with given parameters, like "python HHBD.py 123456789 C:\test\ c:\dest" where "123456789" comes from the password field, "C:\test\" comes from the backup_dir field and "C:\dest" comes from the destination_dir field

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>395</width>
    <height>303</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Huawei HiSuite Backup Decrypter</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>J:/Downloads_2/huawei.png</normaloff>J:/Downloads_2/huawei.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>151</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Select HiSuite Backup Folder</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>381</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>151</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Select Destination Folder</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>381</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>381</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>2</number>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Type here the password given during the creation of the backup of the mobile device with Huawei HiSuite.</string>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTextEdit" name="password">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>190</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>151</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Decrypt HiSuite Backup</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap>J:/Downloads_2/Aantekening 2019-10-24 141833.png</pixmap>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: You haven't really described the problem(s) you're having other than `"...everything goes wrong"`.  Having said that, one obvious issue is that `process` is declared as a local variable in `MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked` so it will go out of scope and have its destructor called immediately after the call to `process.start(pythonCommand)`.

Comment: Hey @G.M., as a non-programmer/coder and less than a newbie in python and QT Creator I'm getting lost in your reply. 
Clarifying the "everything" is that I don't get the result I want. Nothing happens unless the remark "QProcess: Destroyed while process ("python") is still running." that I just noticed. Can you explain me in noob language what is wrong and why?

Comment: From the 2nd glance: `" backup_dir.replace('/','\\')"` and `" destination_dir.replace('/','\\')"` are constant strings and passed literally. Instead, you could use e.g. extracted strings from `ui->textEdit` and `ui->textEdit2`.

Comment: What Scheff says. I would also always use the start() overload taking the arguments as a QStringList, as it avoids quoting issues

Comment: @Scheff: Edited the tag, i did the " backup_dir.replace('/','\\')" and " destination_dir.replace('/','\\')" to show the folder path in windows format. The HHBD.py-script needs the parameters in windows-format i guess?

Comment: I don't know `HHBD.py` but usually file functions in Windows can handle `/` as well AFAIK.

Comment: However, that was not the point. In C++, quotes (e.g. `"text"`) denote a constant string. Whether it contains function calls or variables (e.g. `"sin(3.141)"`) doesn't matter - it will be always handled literally (and result in `sin(3.141)`). AFAIK, that's the same in Python (but it can be different in other languages e.g. in the bash script, variables in quoted text _are_ evaluated: `HELLO=Hello ; echo "Say $HELLO"` outputs [`Say Hello`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d98b146aae2c250c)).

Comment: so loose the ".replace('/','\\')" in my arguments....any idea to get python to run my external script with those arguments?

Comment: `"python " + scriptFile + " passwordstring" + " backup_dir" + " destination_dir";` will result in `python ./HHBD.py passwordstring backup_dir destination_dir` **literally**. It will not replace `backup_dir` by something else just because you have a variable `backup_dir` somewhere. (That, it's a local variable in yet another function is irrelevant here.)

Comment: @Scheff How do i get the data from the variable in my arguments? I assumed that when I showed the data in a text-field (converting the slashes) i could use the same variable in the assumption it would hold my data

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't expose (or give any hint) of what `class`es your text fields are. Hence, initially, I gave you the hint that you could obtain the contents of that text fields to add it to your command line. I couldn't be more specific without knowing the `class` of `ui->textEdit` or `ui->textEdit2`.

Comment: @Scheff So this would be the reult? "QString pythonCommand = "python " + scriptFile + ui->password + ui->textEdit + ui->textEdit_2;" Classes are QTextEdit

Comment: No. `ui->textEdit` provides a pointer to the widget instance. The contents (the text) is in the widget instance. You have to retrieve it from there. Please (please) tell me what type `ui->textEdit` does have. (Then, I can tell you which method can be used to retrieve the text and how you can find out yourself.)

Comment: @Scheff I'm feeling like you get annoyed by my knowledge of this all. I told in the beginning "non-programmer/coder and less than a newbie in python and QT Creator". I have no idea what you need from me. Where can I find out what type "ui->textEdit" is? Sorry to get on your nerves :-(

Comment: 1. If I would've been annoyed I just had removed my comments and would've gone away. ;-) 2. Non-programmer and C++ are a bad mixture - you probably already realized this. 3. You probably composed the UI in QDesigner. I never used it though I know for what it's good for and roughly can guess how it works. Please, [edit] your question and add the code of `ui_mainwindow.h`. That (probably) answers my question.

Comment: @­Scheff Edited the question with mainwindow.h. Hope this is what you need. I do get that I won't try something like this (python, C++,...) anymore. Have my own set of skills whih are not in programming ;-) Thanks for you patience.

Comment: Addes mainwindow.ui when noticed that there is no ui_mainwindow.h <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mtTw0fn/main.png" alt="main" border="0">

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a debugger does. Its job isn't to find bugs for you. Its job is to provide you a tool that **you** can use to find bugs. You can set breakpoints in your code, run it under the debugger (F5 on Windows), it'll stop at the breakpoint(s) and you can inspect variable contents and see how they differ from what you expect. Bugs in software all reduce to invalid state: you expected the program to be in state A, but instead it's in state B. The state is the contents of all variables and dynamic objects. Your code's job is to morph this state. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is such a small program that it doesn't make sense to spread it across three files. You can put it all in `main.cpp`.

The example below is complete and compileable. The entire file is 129 lines long. You can download the complete project from https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/script-frontend-58555092.

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the example application]

First, let's start with the main window. You don't need to use `QMainWindow` since that's for "big" applications with menus etc. All you need is a plain `QWidget`:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/script-frontend-58555092
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <initializer_list>

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
```

The `QProcess` instance is held for the lifetime of the window, so that instead of starting a detached process, we can monitor its state and output:

```
   QProcess process;
```

The UI is so simple that its elements can be easily provided as members:

```
   QGridLayout layout{this};
   QPushButton selectSource{tr("Select HiSuite Backup Folder")};
   QLineEdit source;
   QPushButton selectDestination{tr("Select Destination Folder")};
   QLineEdit destination;
   QLabel instruction{tr(
       "Type here the password given during the creation of "
       "the backup of the mobile device with Huawei HiSuite.")};
   QLineEdit password;
   QPushButton decrypt{tr("Decrypt HiSuite Backup")};
   QTextBrowser output;

   QFileSystemModel fsModel;
   QCompleter fsCompleter{&fsModel};

   QTextCharFormat statusFormat, commandFormat, stdoutFormat, stderrFormat;

   void setupUi();
   void doDecrypt();
   void onStateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState state);

  public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};
```

Notice how all user-visible strings are wrapped with `tr()` so that they can be easily translated using Qt Linguist.

The UI setup is factored out, and is rather uncontroversial. The path input fields have a filesystem completer, to make it easier to enter the paths manually.

```
void MainWindow::setupUi() {
   setWindowTitle(tr("Huawei HiSuite Backup Decrypter"));
   QFont boldFont;
   boldFont.setBold(true);
   decrypt.setFont(boldFont);
   instruction.setWordWrap(true);

   commandFormat.setForeground(QColor(Qt::green).darker());
   statusFormat.setForeground(QColor(Qt::blue));
   stderrFormat.setForeground(QColor(Qt::red).darker());

   int row = 0;
   for (auto *widget : std::initializer_list<QWidget *>{
            &selectSource, &source, &selectDestination, &destination, &instruction,
            &password, &decrypt, &output}) {
      layout.addWidget(widget, row++, 0);
   }

   for (auto *button : {&selectSource, &selectDestination, &decrypt})
      button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Preferred);

   fsModel.setRootPath("");
   fsModel.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
   fsCompleter.setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
   source.setCompleter(&fsCompleter);
   destination.setCompleter(&fsCompleter);
}
```

Most of the slots are so small that they can be provided inside of lambdas:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
   setupUi();

   connect(&selectSource, &QPushButton::clicked, [this] {
      auto dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
          this, tr("Choose HiSuite Backup Folder"), QDir::homePath(),
          QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
      source.setText(dir);
   });

   connect(&selectDestination, &QPushButton::clicked, [this] {
      auto dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
          this, tr("Choose Destination Folder"), QDir::homePath(),
          QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
      destination.setText(dir);
   });

   connect(&decrypt, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::doDecrypt);

   connect(&process, &QProcess::stateChanged, this, &MainWindow::onStateChanged);
```

The output of the process is shown in a text browser, colorized to make it easy to discern errors:

```
   connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this] {
      output.setCurrentCharFormat(stdoutFormat);
      output.append(process.readAllStandardOutput());
   });
   connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [this] {
      output.setCurrentCharFormat(stderrFormat);
      output.append(process.readAllStandardError());
   });  
}
```

The state of the process is indicated for completeness' sake;

```
void MainWindow::onStateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState state) {
   output.setCurrentCharFormat(statusFormat);
   switch (state) {
      case QProcess::Starting:
         output.append(tr("(starting)"));
         break;
      case QProcess::Running:
         output.append(tr("(started)"));
         break;
      case QProcess::NotRunning:
         output.append(tr("(not running)"));
         break;
   }
}
```

The decryption sets up the process and its arguments explicitly using the `program` and `arguments` properties of `QProcess`. That way there are no problems with spaces in paths etc. - Qt handles it all for us. Note that `applicationDirPath() + "./foo"` had a periodthat would give path like `C:/path./foo` - such path is invalid, the period shouldn't be there.

```
void MainWindow::doDecrypt() {
   output.clear();
   auto password = this->password.text();

   QString scriptFile = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/HHBD.py";
   process.setProgram("python");
   process.setArguments({QDir::toNativeSeparators(scriptFile), password,
                         QDir::toNativeSeparators(source.text()),
                         QDir::toNativeSeparators(destination.text())});
   output.setCurrentCharFormat(commandFormat);
   output.setText(
       QStringLiteral("%1 %2").arg(process.program()).arg(process.arguments().join(' ')));
   process.start();
}
```

The `main` function displays the window. The moc file is included at the end, since we don't have a separate `main.h` header file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

This concludes the example.

Comment: Thank you for all this. Got it running but... even with the "HHBD.py" file on the correct place, still got the error "python: can't open file 'HHBD.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved! My destination path had a space in it, that's why it didn't work. Still strange that i complains about the HHBD.py file but could be that it doens't check the arguments of an external script. Thanks again to Kuba Ober and Scheff